# read value in swiftUI TextField and SecureField for login form with Firebase Auth

Tags: swift, swiftui, scope, firebase-authentication

I have implement a custom Viwe TextField / CustomField in swiftUI:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ExtraTextField: View {
    
    @State public var mytext: String
    
    let textTitle: String
    let icon: String
    let secure: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: icon)
                    if (secure){
                        SecureField(textTitle, text: $mytext)
                    }else{
                        TextField(textTitle, text: $mytext)
                    }
                }.modifier(customViewModifier(roundedCornes: 6, startColor: .yellow, endColor: .orange, textColor: Color(red: 0.17, green: 0.24, blue: 0.31)))
            }.padding()
        }
}

struct customViewModifier: ViewModifier {
    var roundedCornes: CGFloat
    var startColor: Color
    var endColor: Color
    var textColor: Color
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .padding()
            .background(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [startColor, endColor]), startPoint: .topLeading, endPoint: .bottomTrailing))
            .cornerRadius(roundedCornes)
            .padding(3)
            .foregroundColor(textColor)
            .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: roundedCornes)
                        .stroke(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [startColor, endColor]), startPoint: .topLeading, endPoint: .bottomTrailing), lineWidth: 2.5))
            .font(.custom("Open Sans", size: 15))
            .disableAutocorrection(true)
            .autocapitalization(.none)
            //.shadow(radius: 10)
    }
}
```

And in another file swiftUI i have implement a view for registration with Fidebase, code is:

```
struct RegisterView: View {

@State private var isShowMainView = false

@State var email: String
@State var passw: String

var body: some View {
    VStack{
        NavigationLink(destination: MainView(),isActive: $isShowMainView){}
        ExtraTextField(mytext: email, textTitle: "username", icon: "person.crop.circle.fill", secure: false)
        ExtraTextField(mytext: passw, textTitle: "password", icon: "key.fill", secure: true)
        
        Button(action: {
                print("email  :\(email)")
                print("password:\(passw)")
                register()}){
            ExtraViewButton(namebutton: "Registrati", iconbutton: "person.crop.circle.fill")
        }
    }
    .padding()
}

func register(){
    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: passw) { authResult, error in
        if error != nil {
            print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
            print("email  :\(email)")
            print("password:\(passw)")
        } else{
            // registrazione riuscita accesso all'app
            self.isShowMainView = true
        }
    }
}
```

}

but I can't pass the entered values email and password in func register(), in call "Auth.auth().createUser()", how do I get the "scope" of the variables in this case?

help me! please.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: when I print email and password variable in register func i not have value assigned. nothing is printed on the screen

Comment: Where is your `ExtraTextField` code

Comment: ExtraTextField code is in another file swift, becouse I want reuse code. the code is posted on the first part of my question. the "secure" Bool variable defines whether the text field should be textField or secureField

Comment: Well I'm pretty certain your problem lies there in that file, because the values that it accepts: for `email` and `passw` should be a publisher, i.e. prefixed with the $ symbol.

Comment: just as a tip: always paste all relevant code. That `ExtraTextField` code should be part of this question

Comment: ExtraTextField code is on top the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after getting the information needed in the comments, yes I'm certain your problem is in your `ExtraTextField`

Change the `@State public var mytext: String` to `@Binding var my text: String`

Then build and let Xcode generate some errors for you to say that you are missing parameters. Hit the auto fix and let Xcode add the missing parameters.

Then add in `$email` and `passw` respectively.

And you'll get another error if you're using previews.. just pass in `constant("") to get pass that.

Let me know if that works, I didnt copy and paste code here to avoid the errors with Firebase but let me know

Updated with code:

```
     struct ExtraTextField: View {
        
        @Binding public var mytext: String
        
        let textTitle: String
        let icon: String
        let secure: Bool
        
        var body: some View {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: icon)
                        if (secure){
                            SecureField(textTitle, text: $mytext)
                        }else{
                            TextField(textTitle, text: $mytext)
                        }
                    }.modifier(customViewModifier(roundedCornes: 6, startColor: .yellow, endColor: .orange, textColor: Color(red: 0.17, green: 0.24, blue: 0.31)))
                }.padding()
            }
    }

struct ETPreviews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ExtraTextField(mytext: .constant(""), textTitle: "", icon: "", secure: false)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have an erron on previews function, when pass constant value at mytext. the error returned is "Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Binding<String>'" for Binding mytext String.

Comment: just updated with some code for that view